# Trying to send a property of an array object to innerHTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, innerhtml

I want to send some text strings that are stored as values of objects in an array.

HTML:

```
<body onload="insertOption()";>
<p id='governmentOption'></p>
<p id='ngoOption'></p><br>
<p id='societyOption'></p>
```

Javascript:

```
//an object with the strings I want to grab
var option1 = {
    optionGovernment: "text1",
    optionNGO: "text2",
    optionSociety: "text3"
}


//array of objects, each of which has three strings in them
var optionArray = [option1, option2, option3];


//the function that puts the object's strings into the HTML
function insertOption (){       
    document.getElementById('governmentOption').innerHTML = optionArray[0].optionGovernment;
    document.getElementById('ngoOption').innerHTML = option1.optionNGO;
    document.getElementById('societyOption').innerHTML = option1.optionSociety;
}
```

If I use `option1.optionGovernment` in the `insertOption` function then it all works correctly.

If I try to substitute `option1` with `optionArray[0]` then not only does that `innerHTML` not work, the other two (which I leave as `option1`) also fail to display.

What am I doing wrong with this array?

(I would rather not use jQuery for this task, even if there is an elegant solution with that – I'm trying to get a solid handle on Javascript (not there yet!) before touching jQuery, and this is just a personal project).

Comment: What has the community come to that you can't ask a JavaScript question without feeling you need a paragraph long reason to not want to use a specific library?

Comment: Shouldn't there be an error in the console when you create optionArray? option2 and option3 is not there.

Comment: Works for me. Which browser are you using?

Comment: It works http://jsfiddle.net/8VDNf/ after adding `option2` and `option3`

Comment: `var optionArray = [option1, option2, option3];` --> I assume `option2` and `option3` are set?

Comment: works for me to (even IE 8), @Cerbrus, yes they are. Despite they're empty ..

Comment: @nozzleman: What do you mean? You can't initialize the array if the object haven't been initialized, yet.

Comment: @Cerbrus sorry, my fault. I assumed Muthu Kumaran's fiddle is identical to the code above... should have looked at his just a bit closer

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys – I just needed to make sure that everything in the array was properly accounted for!

Comment: @Incognito ha, no idea. I just did a search of the records here for answers and found a lot of answers for this kind of question tell the questioner to use a two-line jQuery solution.

Comment: @MichaelSmith, please post your solution as an answer so future users can benefit from your knowledge - you also earn reputation for your profile!